# How to add and remove items from array with a text input field using for-loop, and splice or array methods

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop, dom

i have taken a text box as input field to add elements(numbers) into an empty array. and remove elements from that array on button clciks. i have two buttons add btn and remove button. on clicking add btn whatever input we give in the text box it will be added to the array. on clicking the remove button whatever number is in the input field. that number should be removed from the array along with the duplicates.

the problem i am facing is when more duplicates of similar elements are there in the array. all the similar elements are not removing from the array on button click. some elements are remaining in the array.

```
let array = []


function add(n) {
    let input = document.getElementById("number").value
    let output = document.getElementById("arrayElements")

    array.push(input)
    output.innerHTML = "Value added to the array :" + array
}


function remove(n) {
    let input = document.getElementById("number").value
    let output = document.getElementById("arrayElements")

    // for (let i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
//     if (array[i] == input) {
    //         delete array[i]
    //     }
    // }

    for (let i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
        // debugger
        const index = array.indexOf(input)
        if (index != -1) {
            array.splice(index, 1)
        }
        console.log("array", array);
    }

    // array = array.filter(item => item !== input)
    // console.log(array);

    output.innerHTML = "Value removed from the array :" + newarr
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue arises because you're modifying the array while iterating over it, causing index mismatches.

Here are two approaches:

1. Using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter): More idiomatic, avoids issues with array modification.
2. Using [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) in a while loop: Will remove all occurrences without
   index problems.

```js
let array = [];

function add() {
    let input = parseInt(document.getElementById("number").value, 10);
    let output = document.getElementById("arrayElements");
    array.push(input);
    output.innerHTML = `Value added to the array: [${array.join(', ')}]`;
}

function remove() {
    let input = parseInt(document.getElementById("number").value, 10);
    let output = document.getElementById("arrayElements");
    // Approach 1: Using filter
    array = array.filter(item => item !== input);
    // Approach 2: Using splice in while loop
    // let index = array.indexOf(input);
    // while (index !== -1) {
    //    array.splice(index, 1);
    //    index = array.indexOf(input);
    // }
    output.innerHTML = `Value removed from the array: [${array.join(', ')}]`;
}
```

```css
#arrayElements {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Array Manipulation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="number" id="number" placeholder="Enter a number">
    <button onclick="add()">Add</button>
    <button onclick="remove()">Remove</button>
    <div id="arrayElements"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Other changes that are not the core answer for the question:

- Remove parameter `n` in add and remove functions since it's not used.
- Fix the output to display the current array.
- Use template literals for better string formatting.
- Currently, input values are being stored as strings. Even after adding `type="number"` to the input, JavaScript will still read the input value as a string. So you'll still need to convert it to a number using `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` depending on your use case.